# Did Chomsky adress Multiword Expressions?

Tags: generative-grammar, chomsky

I am not aware of a discussion/definition of multi word expressions by Chomsky? As there exist plethora of "synonyms" (to keep it easy lets state they are synonyms) including compounds, frozen expressions and collocations (to mention just a few) it is hard to find out by just using a search engine.

Comment: What is a multiword expression? Is this one?

Comment: There are lots of possible definitions, but to provide at least one without losing myself: let's define them as "words with spaces", e.g. "black hole", "hard drug", "prime minister" if we reduce it to nominals.(so, yes, multi word expression is a multi word expression)

Comment: These are generally known as "compounds".

Comment: As stated above

Comment: Ray Jackendoff has written extensively on this and if I remember it correctly he criticized Chomsky for dismissing (or ignoring) such expressions.